# Will upgrading my 2007 mac-mini from Tiger to Snow Leopard be a performance upgrade?

Tags: snow-leopard, upgrade, mac-mini, performance

I'm cleaning my old 2007 mac-mini and am wondering whether I should upgrade it to Snow Leopard while I'm at it?
I want to do this only if this will be any performance upgrade.
Note that I have upgraded it's memory from 1GB to 2GB.

Thanks in advance,
Ittai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is advisable to upgrade to Snow Leopard in your case. More specifically, it's very advisable to upgrade from Tiger to Leopard (10.5) at the very least. This will ensure that you can use newer software and hardware that is on the market these days.

Personally, I didn't notice massive performance increases between Leopard and Snow Leopard, but on paper it is designed to better take advantage of the hardware in your Mac Mini. You'll also see alot of new features that have been incorporated into 10.5 and 10.6 since Tiger.

You'll have to source a copy from eBay or something as now Apple only sell OS X Lion (10.7) through the App Store.

Comment: thanks macaco, actually I should have just made it clear that I want to od this only if it won't be a performance downgrade (as many windows upgrades are). From what you're saying I understand that that's not the case, right?

Comment: I'd second this. Leopard and Snow Leopard were both performance upgrades, albeit minor ones depending on individual circumstance. They did a pretty good job of avoiding any downgrade. I'd say you're pretty safe.